# getJSON not working within a function for event change

Tags: jquery, flask

I would like to use `getJSON` to grab properties of an item that a user selects from a drop down menu.

However, when I place `$.getJSON` in a function that is activated by the drop down selection it does not work.

```js
//DOES NOT WORK :(
var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
function json_tolerances() {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_json_tolerances', { machine: $('#machine').val() }, function(data){
         tolerances(data);
    });
};
$('#machine').change(json_tolerances);
```

Strangely, when I place $.getJSON outside the function it works. Unfortunately, it is now not tied to my dropdown menu.

```js
//WORKS :)
var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_json_tolerances', { machine: $('#machine').val() }, function(data){
    tolerances(data);
});
```

More strangely, when I hand code in the array that `$.getJSON` is suppose to provide it works, so it is something to do with `$.getJSON`.

```js
//WORKS :)
var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
function json_tolerances() {
    //$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_json_tolerances', {machine: $('#machine').val()}, function(data){
    var data = {"result": [{"form_field": "polyethylene", "maximum": "-110", "minimum": "-80"}, {"form_field": "air", "maximum": "-993", "minimum": "-983"}, {"form_field": "acrylic", "maximum": "135", "minimum": "105"}, {"form_field": "water", "maximum": "4", "minimum": "-4"}]}
    tolerances(data);
    //});
};
$('#machine').change(json_tolerances);
```

I'm a newbie to javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem you're observing? are you seeing an error? is nothing happening at all?

Comment: not sure 100% but I would suggest adding a "return false" before you close the function parenthesis.

Comment: No errors are shown for all three methods in chrome console. As I am new to javascript, I'm not sure if chrome console is the best way to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Placing everything in `(document).ready(function() {})` solved this issue for me. This may have something to do with the asynchronous nature of `$.getJSON`...

```js
(document).ready(function() {
    var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
    function json_tolerances() {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_json_tolerances', { machine: $('#machine').val() }, function(data){
        tolerances(data);
        });
    };
    $('#machine').change(json_tolerances);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
function json_tolerances() {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_json_tolerances', { machine: $('#machine').val() }, function(data){
         tolerances(JSON.parse(data));
    });
};
$('#machine').change(json_tolerances);
```

Comment: Shouldn't have to play spot the difference. Use your words; explain what you've changed/added and why.

Comment: It's not a problem with $.getJSON.
The difference is that your first example return object as string (json-format), and the 2nd returns real Object

Comment: the getjSON method already calls $.parseJSON on the returned data - also note that the first code snippet the O.P. has indicated works

Comment: It seem that this question was also raised here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788260/jquery-getjson-not-working-within-a-function) ,however, no solution was given.