# jQuery: handle errors in getJSON()?

Tags: jquery, json, error-handling

How do I handle 500 errors when using jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)?

There have been a couple of questions about error handling with `getJSON()` [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740218/error-handling-in-getjson-calls) [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-wh), but I'm not working with JSONP, just ordinary JSON.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572991/jquery-getjson-doesnt-trigger-callback/573044#573044) suggests using `.ajaxSetup()` before calling `getJSON()`, so I tried this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  "error":function() {   
    alert('Error!');
}});
$.getJSON('/book_results/', function(data) { # etc
```

But I find that the alert always triggers, even when the result is well-formed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show an example of whats being returned and triggering the alert?

Comment: it fires the "error" function because it didnt exist and you just made one :)

Comment: @Bob - thanks - what's creating the error? :)

Comment: In this case, you were creating a function called error. But what the real error is, I don't know because i don't have your files :) Thx for the mark, hope you'll find your error!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `getJSON` method does not natively return errors but you could dive into the xhr object that is returned as a parameter in the callback.

The `getJSON` method is a shorthand function for `jQuery.ajax`. Using `jQuery.ajax` you can easily achieve error handling:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/path/application.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
      alert( "SUCCESS:  " + data );
    },
    error: function( data ) {
      alert( "ERROR:  " + data );
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the jquery version 1.5 or higher you can use the new methods .success(function), .error(function) and .complete(function)

Example from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.get("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

// perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
```

Works perfect for me. I hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

you can see it on jquery api getJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON(url).done(function(data){
   $("#content").append(data.info);
})
.fail(function(jqxhr){
   alert(jqxhr.responseText);
});
```

//**jquery1.5+** 
the fail callback will trigger when text is not the correct json string or any other fail solutions

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery 3.2.1:

```
$.getJSON('/api/feed/update', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.error(jqXHR);
    console.error(textStatus);
    console.error(errorThrown);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please do the following. Pseduo code:

```
$.getJSON('/path/to_your_url.do?dispatch=toggle&'  + new Date().getTime(),    function(data, status, xhr){

    if( xhr.status == 200 )
      // all good and do your processing with 'data' parameter( your response)
    else { 
      //error - check out the values for only in chrome for 'console'
     console.log(xhr.status);
     console.log(xhr.response);
     console.log(xhr.responseText)
     console.log(xhr.statusText);
    }
}
```