# Cross domain restriction

Tags: jquery, django

This is how i am passing a json object in `views.py`

```
json_data = json.dumps(filedata, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__,indent=4)    
return HttpResponse(json_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

And I am reading the file in jquery using ajax...

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/defparser/",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: function(data) {
       alert('Fetched ' + data.length + ' items!');
   });
```

But its showing an error saying data is null in the browser...
There is a problem of cross domain restriction because i am accessing a django server file from a standalone html file....
How to resolve it????

Comment: You should [handle error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388934/jquery-handle-errors-in-getjson) and post details here.

Comment: Could you add the exact error message?

Comment: Its showing "null data" in error console....

Comment: Have you tried to get defparser url from navigator or with wget?

Comment: yeah its showing the json file wen i give the url in the address bar....

Comment: sorry dat is the case with 'text/plain', with 'application/json'the browser downloads the json file wen it is given da above url....

Answer (score 0):

The callback function should be 3rd parameter to `getJSON` I believe.

[Check out the docs.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

But the example is missleading as it suggests existance of 2 parameter version of this function.