# How do I handle a JSON request that fails when I'm using .ajax and JSONP?

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, jsonp

I am writing a little reddit image viewing app, and it works fine if the user enters a valid sub-reddit. But I'm trying to handle the case of a non-existent reddit and can't figure it out.

```
function load_data(after) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        "error": function () {
            // this gets called every time, even for a valid sub-reddit
            location.href = 'index.html';
        }
    });

    fetchUrl = 'http://reddit.com/r/' + subreddit + '.json?jsonp=process_images&after=' + after;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: fetchUrl,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cycleTime: 1,
        success: process_images
        // error: handle_error <- this doesn't work, because we're using jsonp
        // but if I take out jsonp, my whole app doesn't work any longer, since
        // I'm trying to run it as a local .html file, and cross-site scripting
        // security prevents it
    });
}

load_data(after);
```

This is the response from the server. But I can't handle it in the .ajax method:

```
GET http://www.reddit.com/r/%3Blk%3Blkl%3B.json?jsonp=process_images&after=&callback=jQuery1510605472848052159_1310668370375&_=1310668370433 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas?

I've tried some of the suggestions on here, like [jQuery.getJSON doesn't trigger callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572991/jquery-getjson-doesnt-trigger-callback/573044#573044) -- but it shows basically the same errors every time, with some random numbers for the 'jQuery##### was not called'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually it's a limitation with cross-domain script injection, which is what jQuery uses for JSONP.

Both the [jquery-jsonp plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) and newer versions of jQuery work around this by implementing a timeout. They still can't trap the errors.

A better solution is to use [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) if possible.

Newer versions of jQuery support CORS but the browser and the remote site must also support it.

Current versions of all major desktop browsers support CORS, Internet Explorer only from version 10.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002367/jquery-ajax-jsonp-ignores-a-timeout-and-doesnt-fire-the-error-event/1002797#1002797) to another question.

Essentially it's a limitation in the jsonp implementation in JQuery.  The popular answer is to use [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) js plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some headers on server response to allow cross domain if you want...

Comment: Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: This is called CORS but it only works if the remote site supports it. For instance YQL supports it but the Stack Exchange API does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      //handle the 404 here
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

here is the ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**EDIT**

wont work with jsonp see the answer above by ccurrens

Comment: that will not work with jsonp as the links provided by ccurrens states that jsonp does not provide error handling therefore there are some workarounds also provided in the answer by ccurrens...